# Instantiate an object using a string as its name in Python

Tags: python, string, object, instantiation, using

As it stands, I'm reading lines from a file to create "Monster" objects with certain int and string variables for each object. Every 2 lines creates a single object: one for strings, one for integers.
Example file:

```
Slime,Slime ball
4,0,2,1,5,6,1
Pig,Pig skin
6,1,3,2,6,4,1
```

Here's my code to read from the file:

```
def read_from_file(file_name):
file = open(file_name)
monster_list = []
line_type = 1 #1=Monster Name, 2=Monster values
for each_line in file:
    if line_type == 1:
        #initialize the monster name
        value_list = each_line.split(",")
        name, trophy = value_list #name = first element, trophy = 2nd element
        line_type = 2
    else:
        if line_type == 2:
            #read values for monster values
            value_list = each_line.split(",") #now ['4','5',...]
            value_list = [int(e) for e in value_list] #now [1,2,3...]
            hp,shield,ap,mod,exp,gold,trophy_count = value_list
            line_type = 1
        monster_list.append(Monster(name, hp, shield, ap, mod, exp, gold, trophy, trophy_count))
#monster(monster_name)
file.close() #Close the file
return monster_list
```

Is there a way to alter the monster_list.append(...) line to use the name variable to instantiate a Monster object of the name?
I.e.,

```
name = Monster(name, hp, shield, ap, mod, exp, gold, trophy, trophy_count)
monster_list.append(name)
```

Is this possible, or is there a similar way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this. The reason being (again as far as I know) that there is no practical use for this.

Might I inquire what you would like to accomplish by doing this? Even if it would be possible, I have a feeling there are easier ways to get the result you are trying to achieve...

EDIT:

From your comment I would say you should be using a dictionary instead of a list. This would allow you to do the following:

```
monster_dict[name] = Monster(name, hp, shield, ap, mod, exp, gold, trophy, trophy_count))
```

Subsequently, in the function that calls 'read_from_file', you will be able to retrieve each monster by it's name from the dict:

```
slime = monster_dict['Slime']
```

Comment: I'm all for an easier way. The idea here is to return a list, monster_list, full of Monster objects. At the moment, I have to access these monster objects by using monster_list[0] etc in the function that calls read_from_file(). I would like to be able to instantiate these as Slime = monster_list[0] but use the name, i.e, monster_list[0].name = monster_list[0].

Comment: I edited my answer. Would this work for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Possibly... I don't fully understand dictionaries, but if I call monster_dict['Pig'] - what happens? Does that find 'Pig' in the dictionary and finds the reference is an appropriate Monster object?

EDIT: Oh, I think I see actually. But how do I return multiple dictionaries? monster_dict['Slime'] and monster_dict['Pig'] ?

Comment: Yes, thats basically what happens. You can read more about dictionaries here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

I would definitely suggest reading about and understanding dictionaries, as they are one of the most fundamental and useful data structures python has to offer! :)

Comment: Thank you, that should work! Dictionaries also look rather helpful. It's about time I actually learn to use them! Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to help! I'm not sure I know what you mean when you say 'How do I return multiple dictionaries?' though? Did you mean to ask how you can retrieve multiple objects from a dictionary?

Comment: I had never used dictionaries before so I did not understand them. Yes, I meant multiple objects. Which, by the way, the answer to was "return monster_dict".